# Swift Modal transition partial curl on dismiss got stuck

Tags: ios, swift, segue, transition

I'm using storyboard present modally segue to display a second view embedded in a new navigation controller. For animation I use partial curl. The transition works as expected when pushing to the second view controller. But using self.dismiss on the second view controller will push back, but the first view got stuck in another transition animation...So for a second the view is displayed as expected but then starts to animate again and gets stuck in the middle of animation. I'm able to use the displayed view, so it seems to be a displaying issue.

[image: Partial curl got stuck]

Answer (score 4):

I am surprised this has not been addressed in 8 months.  It still seems to be happening in 14.3.  The only workaround I can find is just to turn animation off on the dismiss -

```
self.presentingViewController!.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

You still get the partial curl animation on the present but not on the return.

Answer (score 0):

you may try this solution:

```swift
let transition: CATransition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 0.65
transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeIn)
transition.type = CATransitionType.moveIn
transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromBottom
self.view.window?.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Code looks good - can you elaborate on why this code doesn't get stuck like the OP's?  More explanation would make this an even better answer.